# Vim :buffers what %a and # mean?

Tags: vim

What do `%a` and `#` mean in `VIM` :buffers window?

[image: Vim :buffers window]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That information is contained in "`:help :buffers`".  I will quote it here:

```
Indicators (chars in the same column are mutually exclusive):
u   an unlisted buffer (only displayed when [!] is used)
       |unlisted-buffer|
 %  the buffer in the current window
 #  the alternate buffer for ":e #" and CTRL-^
  a an active buffer: it is loaded and visible
  h a hidden buffer: It is loaded, but currently not
       displayed in a window |hidden-buffer|
   -    a buffer with 'modifiable' off
   =    a readonly buffer
    +   a modified buffer
    x   a buffer with read errors
```

So to answer your specific question, "%" means the current buffer in the window your cursor is in when you did "`:buffers`".  "a" means a buffer you can currently see.  Finally, "#" is the alternate buffer, which usually means the last buffer you were editing.

Answer (score 5):

In addition, `#` and `%` are substituted for literal filenames when executing files. For example, when editing a Python file, if you type `:!python %`, it executes the current file as a Python file. Similarly, replacing `%` with `#` executes the alternate file. Very useful. :)